Row was updated or deleted by another transaction Spring Boot
hey im new to spring boot and i am trying to create simple crud application using postgres and jpa  when i trying running this project im getting this error shared below ,
its is something related to database , i tried searching for it and they mentioned about versioning issue i dont know what is that, but is simple crud operation im saving data to database and i think issue must be in setup , thaty why i provide my code , please help he here thanks
    org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.Spring.crud.entity.Users#1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:426) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.merge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.doMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:854) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:840) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar:6.6.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy112.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:320) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy112.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:626) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:359) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:515) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:284) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:752) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:174) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:149) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:380) ~[spring-tx-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy116.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.Spring.crud.services.Impls.UserServiceImpl.createUser(UserServiceImpl.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:359) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:380) ~[spring-tx-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:727) ~[spring-aop-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at com.Spring.crud.services.Impls.UserServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.Spring.crud.controller.UserController.saveUser(UserController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:986) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

here my code
dependencies im using
    <dependencies>
<!--        jpa-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        DB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        gettersetters-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


application.properties
spring.application.name=CRUD APP
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/QuotesDb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Repository
package com.Spring.crud.repository;

import com.Spring.crud.entity.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users,Long> {
}

Entity class
package com.Spring.crud.entity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    public Users(Long id, String fName, String lName, String emailId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public Users() {
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    String fName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    String lName;
    @Column(name = "email_id" , unique = true , nullable = false)
    String emailId;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
}

Service
package com.Spring.crud.services.Impls;

import com.Spring.crud.entity.Users;
import com.Spring.crud.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class UserServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    public Users createUser() {
        Users save = userRepository.save(new Users(1L, "john", "doe", "john.doe@yopmail.com"));
        return save;
    }
}

Controller
package com.Spring.crud.controller;


import com.Spring.crud.entity.Users;
import com.Spring.crud.services.Impls.UserServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {


    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userService;
    @GetMapping
    Users saveUser() {
        return userService.createUser();
    }
}

main class
package com.Spring.crud;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CrudAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Also when i run my project i get this
Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)']
    Database driver: undefined/unknown
    Database version: 17.2
    Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
    Isolation level: undefined/unknown
    Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
    Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown


In your service you do:
public Users createUser() {
    Users save = userRepository.save(new Users(1L, "john", "doe", "john.doe@yopmail.com"));
        return save;
    }

but then in your entity you declare:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;

what this means is that you are assigning id (hard-coding) for new User while instructing Spring/Hibernate to generate Id for your Users. Just remove this hardcoded Id (1L).
